# Why can't I link my dropbox app using mergDropbox?

Tags: ios, external, dropbox, livecode

I can't seem to get a response from Dropbox when I call any of the mergDropbox commands. I've setup an app on Dropbox, so I have an app key and secret to pass in the mergDropbox setup command but nothing happens when I do. All this works fine in the demo stack that comes with the external (which links me to Monte's demo Dropbox app) BTW.

I wonder if it has anything to do with the fact that my Dropbox app status is 'development' rather than 'production', but if it is then I'm unsure how to proceed as I am unable to apply for production status until I have successfully linked to the app - which seems like a catch 22 situation to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question was asked on a mailing list, however, I thought the answer would be helpful to others so I'm posting here.

The problem that's occurring is you haven't set the custom url scheme required by the dropbox app to return to your app after linking. When you don't set this and you try and link the app then you don't switch to the Dropbox app and the dropbox sdk logs something like this:

```
[ERROR] DropboxSDK: unable to link; app isn't registered for correct URL scheme (db-c0sbjqyibf12hg1)
```

So what you need to do is enter db-yourappkey as your custom url scheme here:
[image]

Comment: i tried the above it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Did you ensure you used your app key rather than the one above? Should be db-<yourappkey>

Comment: offcourse :P anyways i got the solution. I was adding it in the Custom target properties rather than the URL Types section